# Compile with newer gcc for older platform

Tags: gcc, g++

If my distro comes with a certain version of gcc/g++, and I want to compile with a newer version of the compiler, I know I can build the newer version of the compiler myself and then use it, but anything I compile with it will not be able to run on a "vanilla" distro of the same version as mine.

For example, Ubuntu 20.04 has g++ 9.4 in its repos. Say I want to use g++ 11 (because it has full c++ 20 support). I can compile g++ 11 and use it, but anything I compile with it I will not be able to distribute to other Ubuntu 20.04 machines, since it will not be able to run using only what is available in the standard repos.

Is there any way (e.g. compiler/linker flag) that I can compile with the new compiler, gaining access to new language features, compiler bug fixes, compile time libraries, etc., but link against the "regular" libraries, so that the produced binary does not depend on anything not in the standard repos?